# changes in main.xml are not reflected in the android app in netbeans

Tags: android, netbeans-7

I am new to android apps. I am using the `netbeans 7.0.1 IDE` to develop android apps. I have written the following code in the main java file:

```
package com.test.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class helloworld extends Activity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
     TextView t1=new TextView(this);
    t1.setText("hello world..!!!!");
    setContentView(t1);
}
```

}

This was working fine.
I edited the `main.xml` file to display a `textfield` and `button` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

>
    <Button  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"/>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Of course I have added all the corresponding strings in `strings.xml`. But when I try to run my app these weren't displaying... :( . I mean the same string that was displayed previously was being displayed.

Can anybody figure out what is the mistake??

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by the "android:orientation" statement? Do you want to arrange your widgets in a column? Or do you just want to set the layout of your activity in "portrait" mode?

Comment: No, no i am done with it... i was trying to arrange the widgets horizontally, but i didn't see the previously written attribute and so i was getting an error... now i am through it.. anyways thanks a lot guys for your help... :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove below lines from onCreate method of your activity

```
TextView t1=new TextView(this);
t1.setText("hello world..!!!!");
setContentView(t1);
```

Because you are setting the `contentView` from the `main.xml` and then again you are creating the TextView dynamic and setting that TextView as a contentView. so you are getting the static string `"hello world..!!!!"`

**Edit**

There is a spelling mistake in your `android:oreintation` line which you are using for set orientation. use "android:orientation" instead.

Comment: wow!! That works!! thanx alot...!! and one more... when i try to add `android:oreintation` to the xml file, it was showing error...why is that so????

Comment: @nitish712 Because you are doing spelling mistakes :P :D

Comment: @Dharmendra... it may be a mistake in the comment but i was writing the correct one in the code... and still it is not wroking??? ;)

Comment: You have declare `duplicate attribute` some where.

Answer (score 0):

remove `setContentView(t1);` from your code

Comment: "setContentView()" literally sets the content view of your activity. In this case you are overriding your previous "setContentView(R.layout.main)" statement.

Comment: @RameezHussain yea got it..!! can u clear my other doubt which i have jst now edited... thanx..

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setContentView (int layoutResID)
```

> Set the activity content from a layout resource. The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the activity.

```
public void setContentView (View view)
```

> Set the activity content to an explicit view. This view is placed directly into the activity's view hierarchy. It can itself be a complex view hierarchy.

from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28int%29)

Since you called it two times, the second call did override the first view.

Answer (score -1):

Right Clicck your project and clean it ..

uninstall your app from device or emulator.....

then again reinstall .....

i hope it will work my friend